# Batch file to add echo to each newline in text file

Tags: batch-file, ascii, echo

I'm trying to append echo to each new line in this text file... Since the text file has over 250000 lines I don't see it feasible to go through it and add them individually. Does anyone have experience in this field that could share their knowledge of how to do this... I'm trying to create an artwork with ASCII characters and I didn't realize until after I was done that I wanted to echo out each line... PLEASE HELP IF YOU CAN...

EXAMPLE OF PART OF ARTWORK FROM TEXT FILE:

```
......................................................................................................................................................
........................................................................................................................................................................................................
........................................................................................................................................................................................................
........................................................................................................................................................................................................
............................................................::oOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOo:.............................................................
..........................................................::oO888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888OOo:...........................................................
........................................................::oO8888O8888888888OOOOOOOOOOOO888888888888OOOOO8O8OOO888888888OO888888888OOO8O8888OOo:.........................................................
......................................................::oO8888Ooo::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::oOO888OO::.......................................................
.....................................................:oO8888OO::........................................................................:oOO888OO::.....................................................
...................................................:oO88888O::............................................................................:oOO888OO::...................................................
.................................................:oO8888OO::................................................................................:oO8888Oo::.................................................
...............................................:oO8888OO::....................................................................................:oO8888Oo::...............................................
.............................................:oO88888Oo:........................................................................................:oO8888Oo::.............................................
...........................................:oO88888Oo:.................................:::::::....:::::::::::::::................................::oO8888Oo:............................................
.........................................:oO8888OOo:.............................::::ooOOOOOOo..::OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOo::::.............................::OO8888Oo:..........................................
.......................................:oOO8888Oo:...........................:::oOOOOO8888OOo:.:oO8888888888888888OOOOoo::...........................::OO8888Oo:........................................
.....................................:oOO8888Oo:..........................::oOOO888888888Oo:..::Oo:o88888888888888888888OOoo:..........................::OO8888Oo:......................................
...................................:oOO8888Oo:..........................::OO88888OO88888OO:.::OOo::o88888888888888888888888OOo::.........................::OO8888Oo:....................................
```

Comment: Why do you need this request? Just execute: `type theTextFile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Grab a reasonable text editor, such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org), and do a find/replace. Find `\n` and replace all occurrences with `\necho`. There are obviously other ways to do this, but I think using an editor like this will give you the desired result without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this batch:

```
@ECHO OFF & setlocal
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" ^<"artwork.txt"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo(echo(!line:*:=!
    endlocal
))>"artwork.bat"
```

Put your artwork in `artwork.txt`, the result will be in `artwork.bat`.